# How to wait for for http response before loading child components?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

My getSetup() Method is called from ngOnInit and will get some data which are needed for the setup of a child component (defined in template). 
Actually through asynchronous connection my child component will be created earlier than the data is accessible. So the data is missing.

```
getSetup() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/apicommand/')
        .map((res) => { return res.json(); })
        .subscribe(data => { // SETUP CHILD COMPONENT })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the router there is no way AFAIK.

I would just wrap the template with an `*ngIf="data"` to "disable" the component until `data` is set.